# Is there a way to extend a function in an interface to include a property in TypeScript?

Tags: typescript, types

I have an existing interface in typescript that contains a function:

```
interface Example {
  foo(): void;
}
```

This interface belongs to a library and is declared in `@types/example`.

Recent changes to the library have introduced a function property of that function. I would like to redeclare the interface locally as:

```
interface Foo {
  (): void;
  bar(): void;
}

interface Example {
  foo: Foo;
}
```

that way when I have an `Example` instance, I can call `example.foo.bar()`.

Unfortunately, due to the existing declaration, [I can't redeclare `foo` as it errors with](https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/PTAEAEBcE8AcFMDOx4A8CGBbWAbeAoASwDtJ4AnAM3QGN5QBRDbPUAb31FEoHseAKAJQAuUADcehACYBufAF98+EKAAyPGuhyg0WXPAB0Ug5ERFSFanVAAxPu06ghoidLlcARunLPxk2QpKJGRUtPRMeqwcXLw8onY8cvJAA):

> Subsequent property declarations must have the same type. Property 'foo' must be of type '() => void', but here has type 'Foo'.

Is there a way to extend the existing interface to make this work without modifying the interface in `@types/example`?

Comment: I don't think this is possible, no.  There is an open GitHub issue at [ms/TS#40904](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/40904) asking to be able to merge into properties like `foo`. It's marked as "awaiting more feedback" meaning they want to hear compelling use cases from the community, but so far it seems to just be languishing.  If that addresses your question fully I can write up an answer; if not, what am I missing?